# Store in a variable plain text from remote iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

The source code of a page shows a javascript with this variable, and the browser shows the page normally with the content from "iframeContent".

I want to store that content in a php variable, and strip html chars letting only < p >

```
var iframeContent = "%0A%20%20%0A%0A%0A%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%20%3Chead%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstyle%20type%3D'text%2Fcss'%3E%0A%0A%0A%20h2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%23CC6600%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%20medium%3B%0A%20%20%20%20margin%3A%200%200%200.25em%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F*%20for%20IE%20Quirks%20mode%20*%2F*%20font-size%3A%20small%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0Abody%20%7B%0A%20%20background-color%3A%20%23FFFFFF%3B%0A%20%20margin%3A%200px%3B%0A%20%20height%3A%20100%25%3B%0A%20%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23333333%3B%0A%20%20word-wrap%3A%20break-word%3B%20%0A%20%20font-family%3A%20verdana%2Carial%2Chelvetica%2Csans-serif%3B%0A%20%20font-size%3A%20small%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atd%2C%20th%20%7B%0A%20%20font-family%3A%20verdana%2Carial%2Chelvetica%2Csans-serif%3B%0A%20%20font-size%3A%20small%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ahr%20%7B%0A%20%20border-top%3A%201px%20dashed%20%23999999%3B%0A%20%20height%3A%201px%3B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23FFFFFF%3B%0A%20%20margin%3A%203px%200px%3B%0A%20%20border-style%3A%20dashed%20none%20none%20none%3B%0A%20%20background-color%3A%20white%0A%7D%0Aul%20%7B%20%0A%20%20list-style-type%3A%20none%3B%0A%20%20margin%3A%200px%3B%20%0A%20%20padding%3A%200px%3B%20%0A%7D%0Aul%20li%20%7B%0A%20%20margin%3A%200.5em%200em%3B%0A%7D%0Aul%20li%20ul%20%7B%0A%20%20list-style-type%3A%20none%3B%0A%20%20margin-left%3A%2025px%3B%0A%7D%0Aul%20li%20ul%20li%20%7B%0A%20%20margin%3A%200em%3B%0A%7D%0Adiv.bucket%20%7B%20padding%3A%205px%200em%3B%20%7D%0Adiv.bucket%20div.content%20%7B%20margin%3A%200.5em%200px%200em%2025px%3B%20%7D%0Ahr%20%7B%20margin-left%3A%200px%3B%20%7D%0A.bucket%20h3%20%7B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23000%3B%0A%20%20font-size%3A%201em%3B%0A%20%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%0A%20%20margin%3A%200px%200px%200.25em%200px%3B%0A%7D%0Ahr.bucketDivider%20%7B%20clear%3A%20left%3B%20%7D%0Adiv.bucket%20%7B%20padding%3A%205px%200em%3B%20%7D%0A.disclaim%20%7B%0A%20%20margin-top%3A%203px%3B%0A%20%20font-size%3A%2010px%3B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23888%3B%0A%7D%0Abody%20hr%20%7B%0A%20%20border-top%3A%201px%20solid%20%23CCCCCC%3B%0A%7D%0Aa%3Alink%20%7B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23003399%3B%0A%20%20text-decoration%3A%20underline%3B%0A%7D%0Aa%3Ahover%20%7B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23CC6600%3B%0A%20%20text-decoration%3A%20none%3B%0A%7D%0Aa%3Aactive%20%7B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23FF9933%3B%0A%7D%0Aa%3Avisited%20%7B%0A%20%20color%3A%20%23996633%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A%23productDescription%20h2.productDescriptionHeader%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-bottom%3A%200em%3B%09%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.emptyClear%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20clear%3Aleft%3B%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A0px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A0px%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20div.productDescriptionWrapper%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin%3A%200%200%201em%200%3B%09%09%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20h3.productDescriptionSource%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-weight%3Anormal%3B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%23333333%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A1.23em%3B%0A%20%20%20%20margin%3A%20.75em%200%20.375em%20-15px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20clear%3Aleft%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.seeAll%20%7B%0A%09margin-top%3A%201.25em%3B%20%0A%09margin-left%3A%20-15px%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20ul%2C%20%23technicalProductFeatures%20ul%20%7B%20%0A%20%20list-style-type%3A%20disc%3B%20%0A%20%20margin%3A%201.12em%200%3B%20%0A%20%20margin-left%3A%2020px%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20ul%20li%20%7B%20%0A%20%20margin%3A%200%200%200%2020px%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20ul%20li%20ul%20%7B%20%0A%20%20list-style-type%3A%20disc%3B%20%0A%20%20margin-left%3A%2020px%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20ul%20li%20ul%20li%20%7B%20%0A%20%20margin%3A%200%200%200%2020px%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20h4%2C%20%23productDescription%20.aplus%20h5%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin%3A%200%200%20.75em%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%201em%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20h4%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%23CC6600%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20p%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin%3A%200%200%201em%200%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.break%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20clear%3Aboth%3B%0A%20%20%20%20height%3A0px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A0px%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.spacer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-bottom%3A%2013px%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20img%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20border%3Anone%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.leftImage%2C%20%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.rightImage%2C%20%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.centerImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-bottom%3A%201em%3B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-top%3A%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20text-align%3Acenter%3B%0A%20%20%20%20vertical-align%3Atop%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.leftImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-right%3A%2015px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20float%3Aleft%3B%0A%20%20%20%20clear%3Aleft%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.rightImage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-left%3A%2015px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20float%3Aright%3B%0A%20%20%20%20clear%3Aright%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.imageCaption%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20clear%3Aboth%3B%0A%20%20%20%20padding%3A%20.5em%20.5em%200%20.5em%3B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%20.846em%3B%0A%20%20%20%20display%3A%20block%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20%7B%20%0A%09border-collapse%3A%20collapse%3B%20%0A%09margin-bottom%3A%201.25em%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20th%20%7B%20%0A%09font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20%0A%09background%3A%20%23F7F7F7%3B%20%0A%09border-style%3Asolid%3B%20%0A%09border-color%3A%20%23CCCCCC%3B%20%0A%09border-width%3A0%200%201px%201px%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20td%20%7B%20%0A%09border-left%3A%201px%20solid%20%23CCC%3B%20%0A%09border-bottom%3A%201px%20dotted%20%23CCC%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20th%2C%20%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20td%0A%7B%20%0A%09padding%3A3px%2010px%3B%20%0A%09text-align%3Aleft%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20tfoot%20%7B%20%0A%09font-style%3A%20italic%3B%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20caption%20%7B%0A%09background%3A%20%23eee%3B%20%0A%09font-size%3A%20.8125em%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20tr%20td%3Afirst-child%2C%20%23productDescription%20.aplus%20table.data%20tr%20th%3Afirst-child%20%7B%0A%09border-left-width%3A0px%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20ul%20%7B%0A%09margin%3A0%200%201em%200%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.center%20%7B%0A%09text-align%3A%20center%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.right%20%7B%0A%09text-align%3A%20right%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20%20.sixth-col%2C%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.fourth-col%2C%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.third-col%2C%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.half-col%2C%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.two-third-col%2C%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.three-fourth-col%2C%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.one-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20float%3Aleft%3B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-right%3A%201.6760%25%3B%0A%20%20%20%20overflow%3A%20hidden%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.last%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-right%3A0px%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.sixth-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2015.080%25%3B%0A%7D%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.fourth-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2023.4637%25%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.third-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2031.8436%25%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.half-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2048.6034%25%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.two-third-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2065.3631%25%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.three-fourth-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2073.7430%25%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.one-col%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%2098.8827%25%3B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-right%3A0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20.last%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20margin-right%3A0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23productDescription%20.aplus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20100%25%3B%0A%20%20%20%20min-width%3A%20895px%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A*%20html%20%23productDescription%20.aplus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20width%3A%20expression((document.body.clientWidth%20%3C%20936)%20%3F%20%22895px%22%20%3A%20%22100%25%22%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbase%20target%3D'_top'%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fhead%3E%0A%20%20%3Cbody%3E%0A%20%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22pdIframeContent%22%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%20%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22bucket%22%20id%3D%22productDescription%22%3E%0A%20%3Ch2%3EDescripci%C3%B3n%20del%20producto%3C%2Fh2%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22content%22%3E%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch3%20class%3D%22productDescriptionSource%22%3EDescripci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20del%20producto%3C%2Fh3%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22productDescriptionWrapper%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22aplus%22%3E%20%3Ch5%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22header0%22%3En%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fh5%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22text0%22%20class%3D%22a-spacing-small%22%3E%3Cp%3En%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%2C%20con%20su%20pantalla%20de%207%2C0%22%20brillante%2C%20es%20un%20completo%20compa%26%23xF1%3Bero%20de%20conducci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20con%20navegaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20avanzada%20para%20un%20viaje%20m%26%23xE1%3Bs%20seguro%2C%20r%26%23xE1%3Bpido%20y%20sin%20estr%26%23xE9%3Bs.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22two-third-col%22%3E%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22leftImage%22%20style%3D%22width%3A%20300px%3B%22%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22image0%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F31t4qpIoGVL.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22%22%20%20%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22leftImage%22%20style%3D%22width%3A%20300px%3B%22%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22image1%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F31J9Zp9aJRL.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22%22%20%20%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Ch5%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22header1%22%3EIndicaciones%20de%20conducci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20completas%20sonoras%20y%20visuales%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fh5%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22text1%22%20class%3D%22a-spacing-small%22%3E%3Cp%3EActive%20Lane%20Guidance%20con%20indicaciones%20de%20voz%20te%20prepara%20para%20tomar%20una%20salida%20con%20seguridad.%20A%20medida%20que%20te%20aproximas%20a%20una%20salida%2C%20un%20modelo%20animado%20indica%20el%20carril%20correcto%20que%20debes%20tomar%20para%20tu%20ruta%3B%20mientras%20que%20una%20agradable%20voz%20te%20ofrece%20ayuda%20adicional.%20La%20visualizaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20cruces%20Bird's%20Eye%20te%20ofrece%20una%20vista%20detallada%20de%20las%20salidas%2C%20como%20si%20las%20observaras%20desde%20arriba.%20La%20visualizaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20cruces%20PhotoReal%20muestra%20cruces%20e%20intercambios%20con%20un%20realismo%20fotogr%26%23xE1%3Bfico.%20n%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%20tambi%26%23xE9%3Bn%20describe%20se%26%23xF1%3Bales%20de%20tr%26%23xE1%3Bfico%20reales%20que%20ver%26%23xE1%3Bs%20a%20lo%20largo%20de%20la%20ruta.n%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%20mantiene%20el%20mapa%20de%20conducci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20en%20pantalla%20en%20todo%20momento%2C%20mientras%20que%20la%20informaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20adicional%20aparece%20a%20un%20lado.%20Por%20obtener%20m%26%23xE1%3Bs%20detalles%2C%20basta%20con%20preguntar%20o%20tocar%20la%20pantalla.%20A%20medida%20que%20avanzas%20por%20la%20ruta%2C%20la%20funci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20Pr%26%23xF3%3Bximos%20lugares%20te%20informa%20de%20manera%20constante%20de%20los%20servicios%20cercanos%2C%20incluidos%20restaurantes%2C%20estaciones%20de%20servicio%2C%20hospitales%20y%20tiendas.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Ch5%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22header2%22%3EGesti%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20dispositivo%20integrada%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fh5%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22text2%22%20class%3D%22a-spacing-small%22%3E%3Cp%3EUtiliza%20Garmin%20Express%20para%20mantener%20tu%20n%26%23xFC%3Bvi%20actualizado.%20Garmin%20Express%20facilita%20la%20actualizaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20mapas%20y%20software%2C%20la%20transferencia%20de%20favoritos%20entre%20dispositivos%20y%20la%20instalaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20gratuita%20de%20voces%20y%20veh%26%23xED%3Bculos.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Ch5%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22header3%22%3EGarmin%20Real%20Directions%20con%20Garmin%20Real%20Voice%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fh5%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22text3%22%20class%3D%22a-spacing-small%22%3E%3Cp%3En%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%20redefine%20las%20%22indicaciones%20de%20voz%20giro%20a%20giro%22%20con%20Garmin%20Real%20Directions%2C%20unas%20indicaciones%20de%20conducci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20f%26%23xE1%3Bciles%20de%20comprender%20que%20te%20guiar%26%23xE1%3Bn%20como%20un%20amigo%20con%20la%20ayuda%20de%20se%26%23xF1%3Bales%2C%20edificios%20y%20sem%26%23xE1%3Bforos%20reconocibles.%20Ya%20no%20tendr%26%23xE1%3Bs%20que%20estresarte%20por%20leer%20los%20nombres%20de%20las%20calles.%20Garmin%20Real%20Voice%20es%20una%20tecnolog%26%23xED%3Ba%20de%20voz%20que%20suena%20con%20una%20voz%20natural%20y%20agradable.%20Garmin%20Real%20Directions%20y%20Garmin%20Real%20Voice%20son%20caracter%26%23xED%3Bsticas%20que%20solo%20est%26%23xE1%3Bn%20disponibles%20en%20nuestra%20l%26%23xED%3Bnea%20de%20navegadores%20GPS.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Ch5%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22header4%22%3EActualizaciones%20gratuitas%20de%20mapas%20y%20tr%26%23xE1%3Bfico%20de%20por%20vida%20de%20tu%20dispositivo%20GPS%20Garmin%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fh5%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22text4%22%20class%3D%22a-spacing-small%22%3E%3Cp%3En%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%20tiene%20preinstalados%20mapas%20detallados%20de%20Europa.%20Con%20actualizaciones%20gratuitas%20de%20de%20mapas%20de%20por%20vida%20de%20tu%20dispositivo%20GPS%2C%20tus%20rutas%20reflejar%26%23xE1%3Bn%20con%20total%20seguridad%20los%20mapas%2C%20los%20POI%20(puntos%20de%20inter%26%23xE9%3Bs)%20y%20la%20informaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20navegaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20m%26%23xE1%3Bs%20actualizada.%20Hay%20nuevos%20mapas%20disponibles%20para%20su%20descarga%20hasta%204%20veces%20al%20a%26%23xF1%3Bo%2C%20durante%20toda%20la%20vida%20%26%23xFA%3Btil%20de%20tu%20dispositivo%2C%20sin%20cuotas.Con%20tanta%20informaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%2C%20n%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%20facilita%20la%20localizaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20direcciones%20y%20de%20millones%20de%20POI%2C%20tales%20como%20empresas%2C%20tiendas%2C%20restaurantes%20y%20otros%20destinos.%20Tiene%20preinstalados%20POI%2C%20por%20lo%20que%20no%20es%20necesario%20que%20introduzcas%20esa%20informaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20direcci%26%23xF3%3Bn.%20Basta%20con%20seleccionar%20uno%20(o%20muchos)%20y%20navegar%20hasta%20all%26%23xED%3B%2C%20de%20forma%20r%26%23xE1%3Bpida%20y%20sencilla.%20Tambi%26%23xE9%3Bn%20puedes%20a%26%23xF1%3Badir%20POI%20personalizados%20a%20tu%20n%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT.%20Cuenta%20con%20el%20lujo%20de%20una%20soluci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20de%20navegaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20activada%20por%20voz.%20Habla%20y%20tu%20dispositivo%20responder%26%23xE1%3B%20de%20manera%20inteligente%3B%20tus%20manos%20pueden%20permanecer%20de%20forma%20segura%20en%20el%20volante.%20Por%20supuesto%2C%20tambi%26%23xE9%3Bn%20puedes%20navegar%20utilizando%20la%20interfaz%20de%20pantalla%20t%26%23xE1%3Bctil.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22third-col%20last%22%3E%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22leftImage%22%20style%3D%22width%3A%20300px%3B%22%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22image2%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fecx.images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F41Gcz5dws%2BL.jpg%22%20alt%3D%22%22%20%20%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22break%22%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Ch5%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22header5%22%3EBluetooth%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fh5%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22text5%22%20class%3D%22a-spacing-small%22%3E%3Cp%3ESincroniza%20tu%20tel%26%23xE9%3Bfono%20con%20tecnolog%26%23xED%3Ba%20Bluetooth%20con%20n%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%20para%20realizar%20funciones%20de%20manos%20libres%20mediante%20el%20micr%26%23xF3%3Bfono%20y%20el%20altavoz%20integrados.%20Guarda%20de%20forma%20segura%20tu%20tel%26%23xE9%3Bfono%20en%20la%20guantera%2C%20un%20bolsillo%20o%20un%20bolso%20y%20sigue%20realizando%20y%20respondiendo%20llamadas%20sin%20quitar%20las%20manos%20del%20volante%20ni%20los%20ojos%20de%20la%20carretera.%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3Cbr%3E%20%3Ch5%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22header6%22%3EEn%20la%20caja%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fh5%3E%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22list0%22%3E%3Cul%20id%3D%22list0inner%22%3E%3Cli%3En%26%23xFC%3Bvi%202797LMT%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%3EMapa%20de%20Europa%20preinstalado%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%3EActualizaciones%20de%20mapas%20y%20tr%26%23xE1%3Bfico%20de%20por%20vida%20del%20dispositivo%20GPS%20(indicados%20en%20la%20caja%20mediante%20%22LMT%22%20despu%26%23xE9%3Bs%20del%20n%26%23xFA%3Bmero%20de%20modelo)%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%3EReceptor%20de%20tr%26%23xE1%3Bfico%20de%20por%20vida%20con%20cable%20de%20alimentaci%26%23xF3%3Bn%20del%20veh%26%23xED%3Bculo%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%3ESoporte%20con%20ventosa%20para%20el%20veh%26%23xED%3Bculo%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%3ECable%20USB%3C%2Fli%3E%3Cli%3EGu%26%23xED%3Ba%20de%20inicio%20r%26%23xE1%3Bpido%3C%2Fli%3E%3C%2Ful%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22emptyClear%22%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch3%20class%3D%22productDescriptionSource%22%3EDescripci%C3%B3n%20del%20producto%3C%2Fh3%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22productDescriptionWrapper%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Bluetooth%20Including%20lifetime%20maps%20%26%20traffic%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22emptyClear%22%3E%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if(typeof%20P%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined'%20%26%26%20typeof%20P.when%20!%3D%3D%20'undefined')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P.when('product-description-fix').execute(function(productDescription)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20productDescription.fixTableIssue()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fscript%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A";
```

Comment: what have you tried? Is it really necessary to post the full variable or wouldn't a snippet of it suffice?

Comment: Was someone supposed to understand what that variable was by just looking at it?